# Ordered Dictionary is not updating in python

Tags: python, django, python-3.5, django-1.11

views.py

```
from collections import OrderedDict

request_dict = OrderedDict()
def payment(request):
    request_dict[0] = 1
    request_dict[1] = 2
```

tasks.py

```
from Payment.celery import app
from celery.task.schedules import crontab
from celery.decorators import periodic_task
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from . import views

@periodic_task(run_every=timedelta(seconds=2))
def addQueueTask():
    print('queue_task: ', views.request_dict)
```

My problem is that variable OrderedDict is not updating their value in tasks.py and it keeps empty. What missing is from my side in this code.
Actually def payment is a web api called from postman and assign two values to OrderedDict when called from postman.

Edit: Output for periodic task is given below:

```
[2017-06-09 11:16:41,012: INFO/Beat] Scheduler: Sending due task PaymentConnectionGatewayApp.tasks.addQueueTask (PaymentConnectionGatewayApp.tasks.addQueueTask)

[2017-06-09 11:16:41,016: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: PaymentConnectionGatewayApp.tasks.addQueueTask[bf6d8440-3fad-48ed-88b9-175434913ff8]

[2017-06-09 11:16:41,017: WARNING/Worker-2] queue_task:

[2017-06-09 11:16:41,017: WARNING/Worker-2] /home/saurabh/Documents/PaymentConnectionGatewayProject/PaymentConnectionGatewayApp/views.py

[2017-06-09 11:16:41,018: WARNING/Worker-2] queue_task:

[2017-06-09 11:16:41,018: WARNING/Worker-2] OrderedDict()

[2017-06-09 11:16:41,018: INFO/MainProcess] Task PaymentConnectionGatewayApp.tasks.addQueueTask[bf6d8440-3fad-48ed-88b9-175434913ff8] succeeded in 0.0014399110004887916s: None
```

Comment: `payment` was never called.

Comment: called correctly and values are filled properly but in tasks.py it is not updating

Comment: It's not called in your presented code, can you be sure it was called? Trace-print a message within `payment()` and see how it stacks against the output from `addQueueTask()`...

Comment: actually payment is a web request and it is called successfully from postman but request_dict is empty still.

Comment: I have shown output from celery task in edits

Comment: tell me please something wrong in this code or in formatting of question.

Comment: guys, I have so much google out on this but didn't get any kind of help and I stuck into this please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First point: in your snippet, `views.payment()` is never executed, so obvously it won't update `views.request_dict`

This being said: the celery task and the web server code (I assume something like Django or Flask ?) will run in distinct processes, so each process has it's own copy of `views.request_dict`, so whatever you do to `views.request_dict` in one process will only be available in this exact process. FWIW depending on how you deploy your code (both server and celery) you will very probably have many server processes and many celery processes, and *each* of those processes will have it's own copy of `views.request_dict`.

To make a long story short: do not use mutables global variables to share data between processes. If you want to share state between processes, use some dedicated tool like a database (relational db, document db, redis, whatever as long as it handles concurrent access from various processes).

(Actually and FWIW, avoid mutable globals whatever the context, this will make your life easier in the long run).

Comment: Thanks bruno for your precious suggestion but tell me one thing that how variables are stored in redis so that shared between processes.

Comment: @AnitaAren Sorry but I'm not going to write yet another Redis / Python tutorial when there are already plenty.

Comment: please guide me that how to share information without using database

Comment: @AnitaAren use Redis then. Sorry but I'm not going to do your own job.

Comment: Thanks bruno again for your precious suggestion